# Separate handling for two posisble unique constraint exceptions on the same insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to catch two different exceptions from the same statement in PL/SQL.

- If one exception is raised then it needs to keep on looping
- If the other one is raised then it needs to exit the loop
- And if the insert is successful it needs to exit the loop.

Here is the code I use:

```
create or replace procedure NewCouponGen
IS
  v_min number(10) := 1000;
  v_max number(10) := 99999;
  v_winkel_id varchar2(200);
  v_suc number(1,0);
  v_new_code number(10);
 CURSOR c_winkel IS
     SELECT id
     FROM WINKEl;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_winkel;
      LOOP
          FETCH c_winkel INTO v_winkel_id;
          v_suc := 0;
          WHILE v_suc = 0
          LOOP 
              select floor(dbms_random.value(v_min,v_max)) num INTO v_new_code from dual;
              INSERT INTO WINKEL_COUPON (WINKEL_ID, COUPON_ID) VALUES (v_winkel_id, v_new_code);
              -- CATCH UNQUE EXEPTION
              --IF v_winkel_id != UNIQUE THEN v_suc = 1
              --IF v_new_code != UNIQUE THEN KEEP ON LOOPING
              --IF INSERT IS SUCCES THEN v_suc = 1
          END LOOP;
          EXIT WHEN c_winkel%notfound;
      END LOOP;  
  CLOSE c_winkel;  
END NewCouponGen;
```

Comment: You have separate unique constraints on WINKEL_ID and COUPON_ID, right? Do you definitely want to catch an exception for duplicate WINKEL_ID, or would alternative approaches be OK? (And why isn't your exit immediately after the fetch?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is not to hit the first exception at all. There is a hint to ignore the duplicate violation, but that would apply to both unique constraints, so it isn't useful here. You could query to see if there is already a record with the `WINKEL_ID` and only insert if there is not; or as a single statement you could use a merge:

```
create or replace procedure NewCouponGen
IS
  v_min number(10) := 1000;
  v_max number(10) := 99999;
  v_winkel_id varchar2(200);
  v_new_code number(10);
  CURSOR c_winkel IS
    SELECT id
    FROM WINKEl;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_winkel;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_winkel INTO v_winkel_id;
    EXIT WHEN c_winkel%notfound;
    LOOP 
      BEGIN
        v_new_code := floor(dbms_random.value(v_min,v_max));
        MERGE INTO WINKEL_COUPON TGT
        USING (SELECT v_winkel_id AS WINKEL_ID, v_new_code AS COUPON_ID FROM DUAL) SRC
        ON (TGT.WINKEL_ID = SRC.WINKEL_ID)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TGT.WINKEL_ID, TGT.COUPON_ID) VALUES (SRC.WINKEL_ID, SRC.COUPON_ID);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
          CONTINUE; -- duplicate coupon ID
      END;
      EXIT; -- merge was skipped because winkel ID exists, or was successful
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;  
  CLOSE c_winkel;  
END NewCouponGen;
/
```

The merge will only try to insert if it didn't see that a record already existed for the `WINKEL_ID`, so you won't get a unique constraint violation from that column. If you do get one from the `COUPON_ID` constraint then the exception handler on that inner block enclosing the merge - which exists only allow the exception to be caught - will send you around the loop again.

I've also taken out the `v_suc` flag completely; and moved the `exit when` clause to straight after the fetch - otherwise you will always try to insert two values for the last ID from the cursor; and taken out the context switch from the `select .. from dual` since you can just assign that random value directly to the variable.

You don't really need that `v_new_code` variable either, you can get the value in the merge instead:

```
        MERGE INTO WINKEL_COUPON TGT
        USING (SELECT v_winkel_id AS WINKEL_ID,
          floor(dbms_random.value(v_min,v_max)) AS COUPON_ID FROM DUAL) SRC
        ON (TGT.WINKEL_ID = SRC.WINKEL_ID)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TGT.WINKEL_ID, TGT.COUPON_ID) VALUES (SRC.WINKEL_ID, SRC.COUPON_ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CONTINUE to keep on looping and EXIT WHEN to exit the loop

```
LOOP -- After CONTINUE statement, control resumes here

  select floor(dbms_random.value(v_min,v_max)) num INTO v_new_code from dual;
  IF (v_new_code =='keep on looping condition') THEN
    CONTINUE; --stops current loop and goes on to next iteration
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO WINKEL_COUPON (WINKEL_ID, COUPON_ID) VALUES (v_winkel_id, v_new_code);

  EXIT WHEN v_suc==1; --or other exit conditions

END LOOP;
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the unique constraint violations, and doesn't seem to address the logical requirements either; v_suc isn't being set and you're seeing the value of v_new_code (which is a number) as something you can verify purely in PL/SQL. (Also there is no `==` operator, it's just `-` for comparison).